# Incrementing a formula in excel using the fill tool

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm using the following formula in Excel 2010:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(C7,$C$2,0)),"",E7)
```

When I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or `Fill down` the `$C$2` reference fails to "increment".

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Do you mean 'repeat' or 'increment'? The $ signs mean that a filled formula will always reference that particular column and/or cell.

Comment: @foocode increment (sorry)

Comment: @toomanyairmiles Remove the '$'s - they are telling Excel *not* to increment - it is their sole purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it without the $ signs before the C & the 2. The $ signs act as a hard pointer so the formula currently includes an absolute (static) reference to cell C2.

If you just have 'C2' instead of '$C$2' i.e. a relative reference, when the formula is filled-down it'll increment to D2, E2 and so on.

Comment: Further details [here](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-HP010342940.aspx). Also, please add the terms `relative` and `absolute` to your answer, easier to search ;)